# node-mysql Rethrow non-MySQL errors

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I just switched my node api over to use [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql). It keeps suppressing my errors/stack traces making development and debugging a nightmare. For example, I am writing a new feature and I get this error:

```
/opt/figo/banking/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:78
    throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
          ^
TypeError: string is not a function
```

The `mysql` module is essential re-wording my original error messages. How can I get it to stop doing this? I want to just see exactly where it failed, not where `node-mysql` decided to *rethrow* my error.

Comment: Maybe your error messages are strings and it's expecting them to be `Error`s so they are not logged properly when rethrown

Comment: The code is crashing, I'm not intentionally throwing an error. Here is the conditional in Parser.js:78 `if (!err || typeof err.code !== 'string' || err.code.substr(0, 7) !== 'PARSER_') throw err;`

Answer (score 0):

If you are throwing error it should a valid error object.I think you are throwing string.Try this

```
throw new Error("oops something happened");
```

Answer (score 0):

you are passing `string` instead of `int` 
or `int` instead of `string`

what i mean is, you are passing `value` using wrong `data type`. not to mysql but to other function, check step by step.

check what `data type` of `var` you are passing using

```
console.log(typeof(yourVar));
```